# How to implement only emoji keyboard for Entry?

Tags: xamarin.forms, keyboard, emoji

I would like to implement Custom Entry (Xamarin.forms) when the user focus the Entry, device will show Emoji keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Unfortunately it is impossible without creating your own keyboard, due to Android and iOS platform limitations.

**Long answer**

Default behaviour on iOS is to show the emoji keyboard icon in the bottom of the keyboard. So it is only one tap away from the user:
[image]

Default behaviour on Android is seems to be slightly different and the emoji keyboard is hidden by default:
[image]
Luckily, it is very easy to place the emoji keyboard icon by setting the `InputType` to `Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationShortMessage | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText`:
[image]

If you are still looking to show the emoji keyboard by default, I am afraid you will have to implement your own keyboard view. Depend on your needs you could add few emojis as buttons and etc.

Answer (score 0):

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#customizing-the-keyboard](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#customizing-the-keyboard)

**Customizing the Keyboard**

The keyboard that's presented when users interact with an Entry can be set programmatically via the Keyboard property, to one of the following properties from the Keyboard class:

- **Chat** – used for texting and places where emoji are useful.
- Default – the default keyboard.
- Email – used when entering email addresses.
- Numeric – used when entering numbers.
- Plain – used when entering text, without any KeyboardFlags specified.
- Telephone – used when entering telephone numbers.
- Text – used when entering text.
- Url – used for entering file paths & web addresses.

This can be accomplished in XAML as follows:

```
<Entry Keyboard="Chat" />
```

The equivalent C# code is:

```
var entry = new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Chat };
```